# using template literal when returning json? Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm using express and I want to return some JSON, would a template literal work? What I currently have:

```
resp.status(201).json({
        message: "Customer added to database",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/Customer/" + doc._id
        }
});
```

I want to change to this:

```
url: `http://localhost:5000/Customer/${doc._id}`
```

Would that be permissible?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: why not, you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible!

I recommend this. it's good readability.

```
const message = "Customer added to database";
const url = `http://localhost:5000/Customer/${doc._id}`

res.status(201).json({
    message,
    url
});
```